# GDB getting stuck while listening to an attached process

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, gpu, intel

I am running a simple OneAPI program and want to use GDB to debug it. The code is available on Intel’s GitHub page: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/tree/master/Tools/ApplicationDebugger/array-transform

I am running the debugger with the GPU (Intel GPU) but the GDB gets stuck at:

```
[New Thread 0x7fffe… ] intelgt: gdbserver-gt started for process 364
Will listen for an attached process
SYCL: Using device: [Intel(R) … ]
```

The GDB gets stuck at this point.
On pressing crt-C to quit the debugging, it says

```
0x7fffe… in ?? () from /lib/…/lib_intel_gpu.so.1
```

It only happens with the GDB and GPU combo. The code runs normally with GPU. Gdb also  works if I choose host or cpu instead of gpu.

It just stops working if I try to use GDB with GPU.

Any help please why this might happen.